# In the following code, when doing a runtime analysis what should be considered as the n that the runtime depends on?

Tags: java, time-complexity, runtime, big-o, complexity-theory

```java
public static void method(char[][] c) {
    if (c.length >= c[0].length) {
        for(int i = 0; i < c[0].length; i++) {
            c[i][i] = ’*’;
            c[i][c[0].length -1-i] = ’*’;
        }
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            c[i][i] = ’*’;
            c[c.length -1-i][i] = ’*’;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the above-mentioned code

I need to find what in my code should be considered as the n that the runtime depends on.

My initial guess was n=c.length, but some of who I asked are saying it should be n= c[0].length and others are saying n=c.length*c[0].length. I am fairly certain it is has a runtime complexity of O(n) but I also need to define what n is as well.

Any help on clearing up the matter would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: My advice: stop calling all variables `n`, and instead express the complexity in function of both relevant variables here, `n_rows = c.length` and `n_columns = c[0].length`. And you'll find that the complexity is O(min(n_rows, n_columns)). If you call `N` the total number of char, ie `N = n_rows * n_columns`, then you'll find that `min(n_rows, n_columns) <= sqrt(N)`, and expressing the complexity as O(min(n_rows, n_columns)) is more precise than as O(sqrt(N)).

Answer (score 0):

In the vast majority of cases where the algorithmic time or space complexity of an algorithm is explained, you'll see something like `O(n²)` or `O(log n)`.

I can see how you think this means that:

1. There is always only one variable in the 'formula',
2. That variable is always named `n`,
3. There's a limited set of formulas that can even appear at the `x` in `O(x)`.

None of those are the case.

In fact, A statement like "this algorithm is `O(n)`" **is just wrong** - it's a dangerous oversimplification, very common to see it, but 'wrong', in the sense that it teaches you bad habits and is a nebulous definition. The key is, **the statement must define what `n` even is in the first place**, or it doesn't make sense. For example, the statement:

> Quicksort has `O(n logn)` performance.

is nebulous. Most people who read that and are aware of what quicksort is can intuit the obvious, but given that we're engaging in something where exquisite attention to detail is *required* (computers don't do well with nebulously defined statements, even if humans tend to do allright with them), the above is a bad idea. Here's the right way to do it:

> Quicksort has `O(m * n * log(n))` performance, where `m` is (average) time taken by the operation 'compare one element in the input list to any other and tell me which one is to be sorted higher', and `n` is the number of elements in the list.

Yes, that's a mouthful, but that is an exacting definition, and *is in fact what is meant* when one says "quicksort has `O(n logn)` performance.". That statement assumes you can guess what `n` ought to be, and handwaves away the comparison cost as boiling down to being insignificant or at least constant which they usually are. Key word in that sentence being *usually*.

So, with that background, what is the performance characteristic of the code you pasted?

`o(max(n, m))` where `n` is the size of the input array, and `m` is the size of the first `char[]` in the input.

No, you can't simplify this. Not without more context that isn't available in the code or in the text you wrote to explain your code.

The question: "Is it okay to simplify (that whole lot with the `m` and the exacting definition of what it all means) to a much simpler 'quicksort is O(n log n)'?" - is not a programming question. It's an english / didactics / philosophical / sociological question, and as such, off-topic.

For the same reason, "If I must put this in terms of a single variable, and that variable is to be called `n`, and I can't explain what `n` is, what is the big-O notation of this code" cannot be answered, but those are non-technical rules that don't make sense. Hence, `O(max(m, n))` with an explanation of what m and n are.